# is it valid javascript to access non-numeric key object with a numeric key?

Tags: javascript, object, key, numeric

I have an object

```
data = {
    'choiceA' : 'Long-Wear',
    'choiceB' : 'Anti-Age Lifting/Firming',
    'choiceC' : 'Replenishing/ Moisturizing',
    'choiceD' : 'Natural/ True-to-Skin',
    'choiceE' : 'Smoothing/ Illuminating'
}
```

and I need to retrieve the fourth value given an integer

```
 position = 3;
```

normally I would write

```
 key = $.inArray( position, ['choiceA', 'choiceB', 'choiceC', 'choiceD', 'choiceE']);
 answer = data[key];
```

but is it valid javascript to access the object directly with the numeric key like this?

```
 answer = data[position];  // where position is an integer
```

EDIT:
some bad code I wrote as I'm using $.inArray backwards!
I meant to write

```
 arr = ['choiceA', 'choiceB', 'choiceC', 'choiceD', 'choiceE'];
 key = arr[position];
 answer = data[key];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not valid until you have numeric object "keys", i.e.

```
data = {
    '1' : 'Long-Wear',
    '2' : 'Anti-Age Lifting/Firming',
    '3' : 'Replenishing/ Moisturizing',
    '4' : 'Natural/ True-to-Skin',
    '5' : 'Smoothing/ Illuminating'
};
```

Also, it is important to note, that properties in JavaScript objects are **not sorted**. So your solution is the best way to go as I see.

Comment: I didn't know they were not sorted ... learned something today. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

if you would have tried it, you would have seen that it is not valid. even more it is not working!

```
data[position]
```

would return undefined in your example...

Comment: You are correct sir, I had not tried it and posting this question was an affectation of my mind wandering. Guilty as charged and thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Javascript keys are always strings. If you pass something else (say, a number) it is converted to a string. (For example, try indexing a array with `array["3"]` and it should work
2. Javascript objects are *not* ordered! You cannot get back the i-th key value pair portably. Instead you should use an array to store things (or something like that):

   ```
   data = [
       { name:'choiceA', value: 'Long-Wear'},
       { name:'choiceB', value: 'Anti-Age Lifting/Firming'}
   ];
   ```

   One thing you could do if you can't change the data representation is iterate though your object using a for-in loop, plus a counting variable. However, this approach is not portable, since not all browsers iterate in the same order as the keys were defined.

Comment: I awarded the answer to the first poster but thanks for your informative answer. Learning a lot today.